# Refining jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am building a simple product filter and have specifications split into types.

I would like my logic to be this:

If selecting 2 specs, each one from different types, the product should match BOTH selections.

If selecting 3 specs, 2 from the same type and one from another type, the product should match the selection from the single type, and EITHER of the selections where there are 2 of the same type.

Example:

Types could be Size & Colour.

I select "Large" from Size, and "Red" from Colour.
Products shown are Large and Red.

I select "Large" from Size, and "Red" and "Blue" from Colour.
Products shown are Large and (Red or Blue).

I have created a snippet with my existing function:

```js
jQuery('.Spec').click(function () {

jQuery('.Product').fadeOut(200);

sClasses = '';
jQuery('.Spec:checked').each(function () {
    sClasses += '.SP_' + jQuery(this).attr('TypeID') + '_' + jQuery(this).attr('ValueID');
});

if (sClasses === '') {
    sClasses = '.Product'
}

console.log(sClasses)

jQuery(sClasses).fadeIn(200);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_1" class="Spec" TypeID="1" ValueID="1" /> <label for="SP_42">Large</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_2" class="Spec" TypeID="1" ValueID="2" /> <label for="SP_2">Small</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="SP_3" class="Spec" TypeID="2" ValueID="3" /> <label for="SP_3">Red</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_4" class="Spec" TypeID="2" ValueID="4" /> <label for="SP_4">Blue</label>

<table>
<tr class="Product SP_1_1 SP_2_3"><td>Large red product</td></tr>
<tr class="Product SP_1_1 SP_2_4"><td>Large blue product</td></tr>
<tr class="Product SP_1_2 SP_2_3"><td>Small red product</td></tr>
<tr class="Product SP_1_2 SP_2_4"><td>Small blue product</td></tr>
</table>
```

At the moment you will see that if you select Red and Blue, there are no matching records as it tries to find products with both these 2 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a selector like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $specs = $('.Spec');

  var types = [];
  $specs.each(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr('TypeID');
    if ($.inArray(type, types) == -1) {
      types.push(type);
    }
  });
  var $products = $('.Product');

  $specs.click(function() {

    var $selected = $products;
    $.each(types, function(i, type) {
      var $checked = $specs.filter('[TypeID="' + type + '"]:checked');
      if ($checked.length) {
        var selector = $checked.map(function(el) {
          return '.SP_' + type + '_' + $(this).attr('ValueID');
        }).get();
        $selected = $selected.filter(selector.join());
      }
    });

    $selected.show();
    $products.not($selected).hide();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_1" class="Spec" TypeID="1" ValueID="1" />
<label for="SP_42">Large</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_2" class="Spec" TypeID="1" ValueID="2" />
<label for="SP_2">Small</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="SP_3" class="Spec" TypeID="2" ValueID="3" />
<label for="SP_3">Red</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_4" class="Spec" TypeID="2" ValueID="4" />
<label for="SP_4">Blue</label>

<table>
  <tr class="Product SP_1_1 SP_2_3">
    <td>Large red product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="Product SP_1_1 SP_2_4">
    <td>Large blue product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="Product SP_1_2 SP_2_3">
    <td>Small red product</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="Product SP_1_2 SP_2_4">
    <td>Small blue product</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `,`:

```js
jQuery('.Spec').click(function () {

jQuery('.Product').fadeOut(200);

sClasses = '';
jQuery('.Spec:checked').each(function (i) {
    sClasses += '.SP_' + jQuery(this).attr('TypeID') + '_' + jQuery(this).attr('ValueID');
    sClasses += jQuery('.Spec:checked').length-1 === i ? "":", "; // you need to add this line
});

if (sClasses === '') {
    sClasses = '.Product'
}

console.log(sClasses)

jQuery(sClasses).fadeIn(200);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_1" class="Spec" TypeID="1" ValueID="1" /> <label for="SP_42">Large</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_2" class="Spec" TypeID="1" ValueID="2" /> <label for="SP_2">Small</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="SP_3" class="Spec" TypeID="2" ValueID="3" /> <label for="SP_3">Red</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="SP_4" class="Spec" TypeID="2" ValueID="4" /> <label for="SP_4">Blue</label>

<table>
<tr class="Product SP_1_1 SP_2_3"><td>Large red product</td></tr>
<tr class="Product SP_1_1 SP_2_4"><td>Large blue product</td></tr>
<tr class="Product SP_1_2 SP_2_3"><td>Small red product</td></tr>
<tr class="Product SP_1_2 SP_2_4"><td>Small blue product</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: select large red and blue you get the small ones too:))

Comment: Hi, this is not working as required, as when you select Large, and Red, it also shows the Small products.

Comment: @madalinivascu yeah! just posted what was missing.